# What is the difference between a discrete and continuous probability data distribution?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

A discrete distribution is one in which the data can only take on certain values, for example integers. A continuous distribution is one in which data can take on any value within a specified range (which may be infinite).

This definition is still not clear to me. I'm looking at a data table showing the expected frequencies of a data distributions. To me this looks discrete, but by definition it should be continuous. This data is measurable, it's not data you can count. The probability falls on an interval from [0,1], to me that is a infinite possible indicating it is a continuous. Can someone help me confirm?

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 0.02464 |
| 3 | 0.05113 |
| 4 | 0.09223 |
| 5 | 0.12772 |
| 6 | 0.159 |
| 7 | 0.159 |
| 8 | 0.13038 |
| 9 | 0.11141 |
| 10 | 0.07198 |
| 11 | 0.04517 |
| 13 | 0.02735 |

Comment: It's not the probabilities that you should be concerned with, but rather the values $2,3,\ldots,13$.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: There are only 11 (finite) possible outcomes

Answer (score 0):

A continuous probability distribution would have 0 as the expected frequency of any value in its range, whereas a discrete distribution takes positive expected frequency on a specific set of values.

What you’re showing on your table of frequencies is a discrete distribution over the integers 2-13

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, *discrete* and *continuous* refer to the *random variable* ($X$). If $X$ = the number of drops of rain falling in Seattle daily in 3026 AD then $X$ is *discrete* (takes on only *integer* values). If $X$ = the amount of rainfall (in millimeters) in Seattle daily in 3026 AD then $X$ is *continuous* (takes on *real* values).

In probability distributions I've seen, if $X$ is discrete, the associated *(relative) frequencies* tend to be also discrete. So frequencies like 0.02464, 0.1141, in your table seem out of place as they have a very continuous flavor to them.